# SlidingTabsLayout height with large pictures

Tags: android, android-tabs

I am creating an app and using the `SlidingTabsLayout`. I am setting the image which is displayed in the tab in the following way:

```
ImageView tab = (ImageView)slidingTabsLayout.getTab(1);
tab.setImageSource(R.drawable.my_selector);
```

This works fine when I worked with images of size 96x96. Now I need to work with images of size 200x200 and now the layout's height doesn't wrap the content, but rather it adds a large space over and under the images, making the slidingTabsLayout to be large in height. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the scale of ImageView

```
tab.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
```

There are lot of scaletypes. You can choose the appropriate from here

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Comment: I also had for some reason a tab layout with padding which caused it. the ScaleType.CENTER helped as well.